# Center a vBox in the middle of a BorderPane in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, layout

I would like to center an hBox with 3 buttons in the middle of a boarderpane.

This is what I currently have, but I cannot figure out how to do the centering.

If someone could help me please.

```
public clas MyBoarderPane extends BoarderPane{

vBox = new VBox();
vBox.setSpacing(10);
vBox.setPadding(new Insets(20));

vBox.getChildren().add(btn1);
vBox.getChildren().add(btn2);
vBox.getChildren().add(btn3);   

setCenter(vBox); }
```

Comment: Please post code you have actually tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `VBox` *is* centered in the `BorderPane`.

The problem is that the buttons are aligned in the top left of the `VBox`. You can change this by setting the alignment of the vbox:

```
vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

Comment: That is it. Thank you very muc. Well, I still do not get it with the panes and all that kind of stuff. For me it is less intuitive as it is in Swing or maybe I am thinking too complex.

Comment: @user3003944, I always set the `background` color to each `Pane` so that I can have some kind of idea about what is going on. This helped me get past the beginner stage of `JavaFX` `Nodes` and `Containers`.

Comment: This is what I had in mind, too :) I think I will do it that way for the beginning.

Comment: [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) is another tool you can use for debugging these kinds of issues.

Comment: @jewelsea - Thanks for the hint. I will consider this tool for my further debugging.